# Sparse matrix insert in c

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am trying to do an efficient sparse matrix multiplication. Right now I am reading the data into memory and this is how my data structure looks like:

```
typedef struct node{
int x;
int y;
int value;
struct node* row;
struct node* col;
}node;

typedef struct matrix{
int height;
int width; 
node** rowList;
node** colList;
}matrix;
```

My current code for the insertion is:

```
void insert(matrix** M, int row_index, int col_index, int value)
{
    node* currNode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    currNode->x=row_index;
    currNode->y=col_index;
    currNode->value=value;

    if ((*M)->rowList[row_index] == NULL) { /* index is empty */
        currNode->row = NULL;
        (*M)->rowList[row_index] = currNode;
    }
    else if ((*M)->rowList[row_index]->y > col_index) { /* insert node to front */
        //printf("%d, %d\n", (*M)->rowList[row_index]->y, col_index);
        currNode->col = (*M)->rowList[row_index];
        (*M)->rowList[row_index] = currNode;
    }
    else if ((*M)->rowList[row_index]->y < col_index) { /* insert node to front */  
        node* rowptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        rowptr = (*M)->rowList[row_index];
        while(rowptr->col!=NULL&&rowptr->col->y < col_index)
            rowptr=rowptr->col;

        currNode->col=rowptr->col;
        rowptr->col=currNode;
        //printf("-----------------%d\n", rowptr->y);
    }

    if ((*M)->colList[col_index] == NULL) { 
        currNode->col = NULL;
        (*M)->colList[col_index] = currNode;
    }
    else
    if ((*M)->colList[col_index]->x > row_index) { 
        //printf("%d, %d\n", (*M)->colList[col_index]->x, row_index);
        currNode->row = (*M)->colList[col_index];
        (*M)->colList[col_index] = currNode;
    }
}
```

In case of you ask, this is my print function:

```
void print_matrix(matrix *M){
    for(int i=0;i<M->height;i++){
        while(M->rowList[i]!=NULL){
            printf("i=%d, j=%d, v=%d\n",M->rowList[i]->x, M->rowList[i]->y,
                   M->rowList[i]->value);
            M->rowList[i]=M->rowList[i]->col;
        }
    }
}
```

For this input:

```
5,5
0,0,1
0,1,2
0,3,3
0,4,4
```

where (5,5) matrix dimensions and (0,0,1) = i,j,value, I get this:

```
i=0, j=0, v=1
i=0, j=1, v=2
i=0, j=3, v=3
i=0, j=4, v=4
i=0, j=4, v=4
```

For this input:

```
5,5
0,0,1
0,1,2
0,3,3
0,4,4
0,2,5
```

I get this:

```
i=0, j=0, v=1
i=0, j=1, v=2
i=0, j=2, v=5
i=0, j=2, v=5
```

I think the problem is here:

```
else if ((*M)->rowList[row_index]->y < col_index) {
    node* rowptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    rowptr = (*M)->rowList[row_index];
    while(rowptr->col!=NULL&&rowptr->col->y < col_index)
        rowptr=rowptr->col;

        currNode->col=rowptr->col;
        rowptr->col=currNode;
    }
    [ ... ]
```

Somehow I remove one of the values when I add a new element that is smaller.

The question is : how can I get this code to load my sparse matrix values into memory using the data structure provided correctly?

Thank you ^^

Comment: What is that data format? Doesn't look like any that I've encountered. Myself, I'd just use [`CSparse`](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/).

Comment: the data format is : first 2 ints are matrix dimensions then on each line in the file we have the coordinates of the nonzero values and the values itself. as in (0,1,5) is row 0, col 1, value 5

Comment: That's the file format. I don't recognise the data structure, your Node and Matrix.

Comment: oh.. misunderstood.. I am not using any standard modes. I use my own.

Comment: the datastructure is at the top. basically a list of list with two pointers. the storage is ordered by rows and columns at the same time without data duplication (only by reference). I need to go through the matrices by rows and columns for the multiplications thats why I have rows and columns in the matrix structure

Comment: Now you are just repeating yourself. What is the name of this structure?

Comment: OK, in that case I don't think I can help you since I don't understand this structure of yours. Why are you shouting? Do you think that will make it more likely for you to get an answer?

Comment: You are right.. I am terribly sorry. Thank you for trying to help. The caps was no intentional although it certainly looks so..

Comment: Why are you using your own more complex format rather than something common like CSC?

Comment: As @DavidHeffernan says, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix for good formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
if ((*M)->colList[col_index] == NULL) {
    currNode->col = NULL;
    (*M)->colList[col_index] = currNode;
}
```

where you write `currNode->col`, you should have written `currNode->row`.  After making this change the output is correct for the second input file.

While looking at the code I noticed other odd things; for example, the print_matrix function also destroys the matrix ->col pointer chains.  Also, in these two lines

```
    node* rowptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    rowptr = (*M)->rowList[row_index];
```

you're allocating memory and then immediately overwriting the pointer to it.